# Monitor works on VGA, doesn't on DVI. Not a broken DVI on display

Tags: display, dvi, vga, nvidia-geforce

I've got a problem. I've got the following setup:

- Nvidia Geforce GTX 560 Ti with 2xDVI (dual) and 1xMini-HDMI
- Asus VW226 (22", 1680x1050)
- Acer V233H A (23", 1920x1080)

I use the Asus as my primary display since it has a lower pixel density (everything is larger thus better readable). Previously I had a 19" LCD as my secondary display through a VGA cable (no DVI on it)

The new screen (well it's second-hand) has both VGA and DVI. Because I didn't have a spare DVI cable I connected it through VGA and after some configuration (it didn't detect the resolution correct and only gave it 4:3 resolutions) it works fine.

I now have gotten a new DVI cable and want to connect it through DVI, but that doesn't work: it simply doesn't detect a second monitor in both the Windows and Nvidia configuration screen. I've tried the "rigorous detection" option in the Nvidia control panel.

I've swapped the ports and then the Acer worked fine, but the Asus didn't: same symptoms. So the displays work with DVI on the first port, but only on VGA on the second.

As I don't have a mini-HDMI -> DVI converter I can't try that port, but does anyany have an idea how I could fix this?

Comment: *I've swapped the ports and then the second monitor worked fine, but the first didn't: same symptoms.* sounds like you already know the problem then

Comment: What Rob said.  This is pretty clearly the DVI port on that monitor simply not working, if you've eliminated the port on the video card and the cable you're using via a swap.

Comment: What Rob and Shinrai said OR you just need to press some kind of input button to change it from vga to dvi.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, English is not my primary language. To make it clear: *BOTH* monitors work on DVI when coupled to the first port, neither when to the second. The second port does pass VGA through fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BOTH monitors work on DVI when coupled to the first port, neither when to the second. The second port does pass VGA through fine"

When using a DVI->VGA adapter, you are only using a fraction of the pin-connectors on the DVI port.

[image: DVI Pinout]

The "C" pins are used for analog (VGA).

If you've tried two different monitors, and two different DVI cables, and it won't work in DVI mode on that *one* port, then that one port probably has damage to the DVI pins (which aren't used for analog/VGA conversion).

Sounds like you need a new video card.

Comment: The card is only 4 months old, So I guess I'll send it to warranty

Answer (score 0):

Before deciding it is a hardware problem,
you should search for the newest driver in the [Nvidia download drivers page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
One can specify here one's card, or even better:
Use the "GRAPHICS DRIVERS" button for Nvidia to automatically suggest the best driver.

As power goes, this card seems to use two power connectors, so I hope you have both main and supplementary connectors well-seated. A sufficient PSU is also required, where [Nvidia specs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html) say
"Minimum Recommended System Power (W) : 500 W".

Comment: Updates drivers barely a month ago. Updated to latest beta but no sigar

Comment: Have you verified the power requirements ? Also, if this computer is under warranty (which model is it?), you might demand to replace the video card, since dual-dvi is *advertised* as working. It might be prudent to first verify this point with Nvidia Support.

Comment: @dtech - Have you tried connecting just one monitor to the second (not working) DVI port?

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems like a similar issue.

It turned out I only had a single-link DVI cable, but the card was set to deliver 32-bit colour depth, which I wanted for photography. Single link DVI can only 24-bit color depth.

Control this setting in the nvidia control panel under "DIsplay/Change Resolution".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Single-link_DVI

You need the extra pins on a Dual-link to deliver the extra bits of color resolution.

Comment: Not true.  Most DVI cables are single-link and support "True Color (32-bit)".  24-bit and 32-bit color depths are both 8-bits per channel and support the same amount of colors (16.7 million), the difference with 32-bit is an additional alpha (non-color) channel.

Answer (score -4):

For all the answerers before I want to advise **silence**: If you don't know what is Dual-DVI, **you must RTFM and STFW**!!!

Dtech - all is perfectly OK with your card, just *unexpected for you*. Dual-DVI means that you can have only **one output device** on **two DVI ports**, two (both) ports used for *single* minitor with exra-high resolution, when single DVI-bandwidth is not enouhg

If you want to have two outputs, you have:

- use HDMI port of this card in addition to DVI

or

- add second card and use it's DVI

or

- replace card and find DVI+VGA or 2 **independent** DVI output

Results (some...) of quicksearch

- Gainward GeForce GTX560 GS (DVI-I + VGA)
- Gainward GeForce GTX560Ti Phantom (DVI-I + DVI-D + VGA)

Comment: I think you're thinking of [DVI dual-link](http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/dvi_info.html#Page03), and that's per-port. I'd bet (without RTFM) that his card supports two Dual-Link DVI connections, because that's usual for the last few years. I'd confirm it, but I don't have an exact card make/model.  Neither of his monitors can do a resolution (according to the user) above what single-link DVI can do anyway.

Comment: Dual-Link is irrelevant to the question, he's trying to hook up TWO DVI monitors to TWO DVI ports, neither of which require the bandwidth if Dual-Link DVI because he's not going above Single-Link's resolution capabilities. According to [nVidia's spec](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html) for that chipset: "Standard Display Connectors: Mini HDMI, Two Dual Link DVI"